# Printing Ruby inside of javascript using haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've been having problems trying to print some ruby variables while using haml, inside of my javascript code.

I have a variable called "@matrix" that is a Matrix. What I need to do is print each of the rows of the given matrix and end up with something looking like the following:

```
  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  ['2004',  1000, 400],
  ['2005',  1170, 460],
  ['2006',  660, 1120],
  ['2007',  1030, 540]
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get the right format using my ruby variable. I've seen some similar problems in stackoverflow, however even after trying different ways of implementing what I've read, i haven't succeded.

My actual code is the following:

```
  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  #{
    for i in 0..@matrix.row_count
      puts @matrix.row(i).to_a.to_s+","
    end
  }
```

Which should give me each row of the matriz (which is just what I want), however the error I'm getting is that the *for* loop isn't recognized, and what is printed is actually *0..66*.

Any approach on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What i've had to do in the past was use a helper to format the data and return the value JS likes.

Comment: I was hoping to get something as simple as what I tried :/ if it is not possible I suppose I'll have to use a helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not want to *print* those strings; you want to *interpolate them*. A for-loop just returns the collection it's looping around, which is why you're getting "0..66". You want something that returns the string you were printing.

Instead of a for-loop, try something like this:

```
(0..@matrix.row_count).map {|i| @matrix.row(i).to_a.to_s }.join(',')
```

(Incidentally, I would not recommend using `Array#to_s` for output like this. Its format has changed before and it can change again. I would consider using something more like `"[#{matrix.row(i).to_a.join(',')}]"`, where you explicitly specify how the array should be formatted.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Chuck, I tried this but I'm getting **wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)**

Comment: @Waclock: Whoops, used brackets instead of parens for the matrix thingy. It's probably related to that.

Comment: It's supposed to be parens I believe (It's a method of the class Matrix). I tried it on rails console (doing @matrix.row(1) ) and it worked without problems)

Comment: @Waclock: Yeah, that's what I said. I accidentally used brackets instead of parens, which is what led to that argument error you were getting. I've never used Ruby's Matrix class myself, so I was just going off your original code and copied it incorrectly.

Comment: I thought you meant the other way around haha my bad, it actually worked! Thank you very much!